# An issue about c/c++ Segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple program to test array pointer:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        int (*array)[10];
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                array[i][j] = 1;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                cout << array[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

why the g++ "Segmentation fault"?
by the way, my os is ios x64.

Thanks
Chuan

Comment: Sounds like another one of steve's new 'features'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array` is a pointer to an array, which you apparently already know. However, you never allocated memory for the actual array, i.e. your pointer is pointing "nowhere". You are trying to access something that does not exist, which often leads to segmentation fault.

For example, you can declare an actual array

```
int array10x10[10][10];
```

and make your pointer point to it

```
array = array10x10;
```

(more precisely, your pointer is now pointing to the first 10-element subarray in `array10x10`). After that your code will work fine, meaning that by accessing `array[i][j]` you will indirectly access `array10x10[i][j]`.

Alternatively you can allocate the actual array in dynamic memory, if you so desire

```
array = new int[10][10];
```

(just don't forget to do a `delete[] array` at the end).

Comment: After reading your comments, summarize my understanding, any king of pointer declare doesn't allocate memory expect the pointer's holding memory. And when segmentation fault happens is not determined. For example, when run program above, it can print right 10*10 array in which every item is 1, then print "segmentation fault". Something wrong with my understanding?

Comment: @kennyeric: I'm not sure I understand your question. When you define a pointer variable, you get just that: a pointer variable. A pointer has to point somewhere. And that "somewhere" is not allocated automatically. You have to allocate that "somewhere" yourself and you have to manually make your pointer point there.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `array` as an array of pointers, then use it as an array of arrays.

You must declare it as multi-dimensional instead :

```
int array[10][10];
```

Comment: Incorrect. It is not an "array of pointers", but a "pointer to array". Which is BTW exactly what the OP is trying to "test", so eliminating the pointer is out of question.

Comment: Oh. I didn't knew about this syntax.

Comment: I think the issue is that I shouldn't allocate the array memory explicitly.